# How can I properly filter nullable DateOnly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dateonly

I have successfully configured a `DateOnly` property on my EF 6 entity as below

Everything is working great, except for the fact that the property is nullable. The issue occurs when I try to filter entities where `Prperty1 < [some-date]`, in that EF does not consider `null` to be less than anything, so it is excluded from the results

How can I get EF to understand that `null` is basically less than or equivalent to `DateOnly.MinValue` when filtering on that property?

I already tried replacing `DateOnly` with `DateOnly?` in my converter, but it makes no difference

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public DateOnly? Property1 { get; private set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
builder
    .Property(x => x.Property1)
    .HasConversion(DateOnlyRelationalTypeMapping.Converter)
    .HasColumnType("date");
```

Relational type mapping:

```
public sealed class DateOnlyRelationalTypeMapping : RelationalTypeMapping
{
    internal DateOnlyRelationalTypeMapping() 
        : this(
            new RelationalTypeMappingParameters(
                new CoreTypeMappingParameters(
                    typeof(DateOnly),
                    Converter),
                "date"))
    {
    }

    private DateOnlyRelationalTypeMapping(RelationalTypeMappingParameters parameters)
        : base(parameters)
    {
    }

    public static new readonly ValueConverter<DateOnly, DateTime> Converter =
        new(
            clrValue => clrValue.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue),
            dbValue => DateOnly.FromDateTime(dbValue));

    protected override RelationalTypeMapping Clone(RelationalTypeMappingParameters parameters) 
        => new DateOnlyRelationalTypeMapping(parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add that check yourself.

Instead of relying on EF:

```
dbContext.Entities.Where(e => e.Property1 < someDate); // does not work
```

add the constraint that entities with `null` date are also included:

```
dbContext.Entities.Where(e => e.Property1 != null || e.Property1 < someDate);
```

Please note that this behavior has nothing to do with EF. That is how SQL compares values. A DB `NULL` compared to anything returns Boolean result `NULL` - neither true, nor false. When a Boolean check is included in the SQL `WHERE` clause, anything that evaluates to a value other than true (that stands for `NULL`, too) will be excluded from the output.

Comment: Will that return entities where `Property1 == null`? I'm not sure if I can take this approach, as my query is sent to sql to be processed, rather than building the query in EF/linq

Comment: Maybe I have misinterpreted your question - when you say "filter", do you mean to keep them, or to remove them? Do you want your query to return all entities with smaller date *or* a null date?

Comment: I have edited code to work in this way, and added an explanation why the database is filtering out entities with `NULL` property.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison should be: is the `DateOnly` property is null OR less than a specified fate i.e.

```
.....Where(x => x.Property1 == null || x.Property1 < targetDate);
```